# Sinatra can't see files

Tags: ruby, sinatra

This line

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="public/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

throws an arror

```
GET http://localhost/ajax/public/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

without 'public' it was the same.

It worked without public after i changed this in my app:

```
get '/' do
    erb :main

end
```

to:

```
get '/sth_else' do
    erb :main

end
```

But I want to load a page just with www.page.com/  with no further arguments. 
Please help me out.

Comment: have you tried using the url-helper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does `ajax` do in your path? If you Javascript files are in `public/js/jquery.js`. You should be able to fetch them with

```
http://localhost:port/js/jquery.js
```

and to be able to include them with `/js/jquery.js` (mind the start `/`)

Comment: You're right. I just had to add /ajax/js/jquery.js.  /ajax/ is one of applications on my localhost.